# How to download GIMP from Ubuntu Apps Directory

Tags: gimp

I would like to download both Ubuntu and GIMP to install on a computer with **no** internet connectivity. I presume simply downloading Ubuntu and burning an ISO disk will take care of the former.

However, GIMP directs me to https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/saucy/gimp/, and the emailed download link from there takes me back to https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/saucy/gimp/: I cannot find anything on that page that would permit me to download GIMP for Ubuntu.

Walton

Comment: Thank you.  I have looked at and printed out the reference regarding offline installations, which would be applicable once I've found the file/download in question.  I'm still looking.

Comment: You can download packages (.deb) from here - http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gimp , but if you do not use the link I gave you, you will have to manually download all the dependencies as well.

Answer (score 0):

In a terminal, enter

`apt-get download gimp`

This will download the gimp package in your current directory

It may be difficult since you are limiting yourself to Windows 7 as a download media for your Ubuntu machine.  You could explore [gimp.org](http://www.gimp.org), but I suspect that you will have problems which exceed the ability to easily allow you to run Ubuntu - during the install process Ubuntu would like to be able to connect to the internet to download updates to the core of the operating system, and to all of the peripheral programs.

One way to do this would be to create a virtual machine in your windows 7 computer, load and install the required elements, and then create an installation USB based upon your virtual machine.  I have not run through the process of creating a boot image myself, but it is documented on [Ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MakeALiveCD/DVD/BootableFlashFromHarddiskInstall)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  Sorry if I'm a bit daft.  I'm in Windows 7, and I'm trying to get both Ubuntu and GIMP to install on a separate computer, which cannot go online.

Comment: @user299846 updated answer with additional information

Answer (score 0):

What I generally do for such situations is maintain an offline repository. If you have an existing ubuntu installation, install aptoncd first:

sudo apt-get install aptoncd

Run this app to create a compressed ISO image from your apt cache. Thus you now have an offline "backup" repo from which you can install any software that you want, not just repo. To use this backup repo, just extract this ISO to any folder you like and add this line in your /etc/apt/sources.list:

deb file:///path/to/iso/extract ./

This will create a working repo from which you may do any offline install.

But do remember that with this method, you are tied to a particular version of the distro. If you created the backup from precise, the backup repo will only work from precise.

Comment: If I understand, you are saying that from an existing Ubuntu system, download/install "sudo apt-get . . ." The catch is, I do not have an existing Ubuntu system. I am working in Windows 7.

Comment: In that case, you have two options: 1). Grab the gimp source from this page http://www.gimp.org/downloads/ and try to build it yourself on win7. Read their help section if you wish to go this route. 2) The other (easier) option is to install ubuntu on a virtualbox on win7 first, then create the backup repo ISO as I've described, make a copy of that ISO and then install ubuntu proper on your machine.

Comment: Also note that if you are going the "apt-get download gimp" route, then make sure you also get the various dependencies. Gimp is just one package, but it takes several other packages like libgimp2.0, gimp-data, etc. to run gimp properly.

Comment: Thank you . . . that makes sense . . . I'll see what I can do.  Thank you!